# Are these approaches valid for getting the largest power of 2 smaller than n?

Tags: javascript

Are all of the following valid ways to find the largest power of two smaller than the value itself?

```js
function largestPowOf2Smaller1(n) {
    if (n === 0 || n === 1) {
        throw 'too small';
    }
    n = n-1;
    let pow = 0;
    while (n > 0) {
        n >>= 1;
        pow++;
    }
    return pow-1;
}

function largestPowOf2Smaller2(n) {
    if (n === 0 || n === 1) {
        throw 'too small';
    }
    return (n-1).toString(2).length-1;
}

function largestPowOf2Smaller3(n) {
    if (n === 0 || n === 1) {
        throw 'too small';
    }
    return Math.floor(Math.log2(n-1));
}

// "Tests"
console.log(largestPowOf2Smaller1(2)); // 0
console.log(largestPowOf2Smaller2(2)); // 0
console.log(largestPowOf2Smaller3(2)); // 0

console.log(largestPowOf2Smaller1(4)); // 1
console.log(largestPowOf2Smaller2(4)); // 1
console.log(largestPowOf2Smaller3(4)); // 1

console.log(largestPowOf2Smaller1(8)); // 2
console.log(largestPowOf2Smaller2(8)); // 2
console.log(largestPowOf2Smaller3(8)); // 2

console.log(largestPowOf2Smaller1(9)); // 3
console.log(largestPowOf2Smaller2(9)); // 3
console.log(largestPowOf2Smaller3(9)); // 3
```

Comment: are you trying to have us solve your homework?

Comment: btw I think none of them work, should largestPowOf2Smaller(9) not equal 3? or am I getting the idea of this wrong?

Comment: @VictorRadu I was thinking the same.

Comment: This is not my homework. I am developing my bit manipulation knowledge...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find the largest power of 2 less than the given number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17379020/how-to-find-the-largest-power-of-2-less-than-the-given-number)